# Can not assign Task or User Story, to project Members in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am pretty new to DevOps. I've created a project in Azure DevOps and then invite some of my colleagues to project using the Invite button.

I can't assign anyone to the board Tasks or User Story. When I navigate to "Assign to" menu, the drop down is empty and there is the only option Unassigned.

[image]
[image]
Where did I do wrong? please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to enter the work item, in the "assigned to" field start type the username and press enter?

Comment: Yay! thanks @Shayki. it works. it's really wired that you have to press the enter to force it to search a user, while it shows me a spinning circle making me wait and nothing happens. pressing Enter, It was cool.

Comment: before your solution, I worked around and changed the members' access level from Basic to Stakeholder, was that necessary? do I need to roll back changes? I have no idea of Access Levels.

Comment: I posted it also as an answer. I agree with you, the UI is not so good! you can read here about the Access levels: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=vsts

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Enter to a work item and in the "Assigned To" filed start to type a username and press enter, it should identify the name and complete it and you can choose the user.

It's really bad UI/UX...!

Comment: 2 hours of working around, it was all about pressing the `Enter` :/

Comment: Thanks for this @Shayki. ENTER was the trick.  +1 to "really bad UI/UX!"

Answer (score 2):

I found same problem, but don't panic for this issue.
You just follow :

1. Open your task/epic/etc
2. Click arrow in assignee field
   [image]
3. Type full username of your team
4. Press Enter
5. Thanks